# Selenium Firefox web driver freezing when multiple instances of the web drivers are launched

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on an app that takes screenshot of a page using selenium firefox web driver through asynchronous tasks using celery. What I have observed is that it hangs while polling if an element has been loaded when multiple instances of web drivers are launched at the same time.

Is there a way I can be able to force close the web driver after some timeout interval?

Or is there some other way I can handle this problem? Any suggestions?

Relevant Code :

```
def open_url_in_virtual_display(self, url, browser, selector=None):
    browser.get(url)

    def find_element(browser):
        log.info("waiting for selector to be loaded : {0}".format(selector))
        found = False
        is_stale = True
        while is_stale:
            try:
                ele_found = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector).is_displayed()
                #it hangs over here.
                log.info(" element found flag : {0}".format(ele_found))
                if ele_found:
                    found = True
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                is_stale = True
            else:
                is_stale = False
        return found

    def wait_until_function_returns_true(browser, fn, timeout):
        ret_val = False
        try:
            ret_val = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(fn)
        except TimeoutException as e:
            return ret_val

        else:
            return ret_val

    wait_until_function_returns_true(browser, find_element, 10)
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
```

This method is launched everytime a request for screenshot comes.

Comment: Could you share the actual code and point the place where it hangs? Thanks!

Comment: This question presents a really tricky issue but does not provide nearly enough information to post an informed answer. For instance the OP has a comment saying "it hangs over here". The natural interpretation is that the *next* line hangs. If `log.info` hangs, that's not a Selenium issue. However, it could be that the element is *already* stale, and this for each iteration (yes, this is *absolutely* possible; eg. the element sought is some sort of real time clock). So the code is actually not "hung" but spinning infinitely. There's not enough information to do more than hypothesize.

Comment: @Louis I don't totally understand why it is possible that the element sought  could be already stale. But let's consider if it is already stale how can I detect that.

Comment: @Mudits If there is JavaScript code on the browser side that is manipulating the DOM it is possible for an element to be stale by the time you use it in your script. It has happened to me in some code that would test a table refresh for instance.